# Automatically add an entry in /etc/hosts file in newly launched amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Things I have done:

```
$ vi /etc/hosts
```

- Added IPAddress Hostname

I want to automate this process like every new instance I launch should have an entry in /etc/hosts

Answer (score 3):

Guess  you need add the host itself in /etc/hosts.

Put this in `user data` when you create a new ec2 instance

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo `ec2-metadata -o|cut -d: -f2` " " `ec2-metadata -h |cut -d: -f2` >> /etc/hosts
```

Comment: If ec2-metadata is not available then you can also use a combination of curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 and curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname.