# How do you manage provisioning Packer EC2 Linux instances that require hostname entries reliably?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, packer

I have a packer ec2 instance where part of the provisioning entails updating the `etc/hosts` file for the instance. Among these entries is the one of the current running machine which is written in `ip-00-00-00` format.

If you do this in Packer, the AMI is saved and launching it again results in a **new hostname/ip being assigned** and the old hostname is irrelevant. The hostname is used for an internal application which relies on its hostname entry as well as oracle client. For oracle client, there is an `ORACLE_HOSTNAME` environment variable entry that can be added.

So how do you manage such a process where you're building an AMI that requires dynamic changes to its host file?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739618/automatically-add-an-entry-in-etc-hosts-file-in-newly-launched-amazon-ec2-insta

Comment: That helps alot! I'll probably answer my own question a bit later